# data type inst converting correctly?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Ok so my .exe is giving me a zero so im guessing that the data type  is not casting correctly. Sorry im new to c++ and came from c. Any time i had this problem in c something usually was truncated, but i cant find out what i did wrong.

```
//shape.h
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
class shape 
{
public:
   shape();
   virtual float area()=0;

};

#endif SHAPE_H


//shape.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"
using namespace std;

shape::shape()
{
}

//triangle.h
#include"shape.h"

class triangle: public shape 
{
public: 
    triangle(float,float);
    virtual float area();
protected:
    float _height;
    float _base;


 };


//triangle.cpp
#include "triangle.h"

triangle::triangle(float base, float height)
{
base=_base;
height=_height;
}
 float triangle::area()
 {
return _base*_height*(1/2);
  }

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"
#include "triangle.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

triangle  tri(4,2);


cout<<tri.area()<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

For some reason i am getting a zero in my exe when i should be getting a 4.

Comment: This: `(1/2)` evaluates to zero. its integer division. Try 1.0/2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned value in wrong way:

update:

```
triangle::triangle(float base, float height)
{
  base=_base;
  height=_height;
}
```

to:

```
triangle::triangle(float base, float height)
{
   _base = base;
   _height = height;
}
```

Edit:

Also as @WhozCraig mentions, should use float for 1/2, or just

```
_base * _height / 2.0
```

Comment: +1. I've a suspicion he's about to find what I mentioned in comment as well (and those really should be in an initialization list =P).

Comment: Thanks! and haha your right i did find it but it still didnt make a difference until i did what billz said

Comment: @FelixDaCat *both* need to be fixed. Either one will do what you had; both  was just overkill. =P

Comment: Thanks billz that worked but why does it matter which way you assign them? could you explain? As I am still learning. Thanks! @billz

Comment: your original `base=_base;` is undefined behavior. you suppose to assign member value from parameter not the other way around